# Schrodinger field and Klein-Gordon field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

In the usual Fourier expansion of Schrodinger fields
\begin{align}
 \Psi(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int d^3 k \hat{a}_k e^{-i (wt-\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})}, \quad
  \Psi^{*}(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int d^3 k \hat{a}^{\dagger}_k e^{i (wt-\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})}
\end{align}
while Foruier expansion of Klein-Gordon fields are followings

\begin{align}
\Psi(\vec{x}) =  \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^{3}2w_k} \left[\hat{a}_k e^{-i (wt-\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})}+\hat{a}^{\dagger}_k e^{i(wt-\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x})}\right]
\end{align}

Here i wonder why the expansion of schrodinger field and klein gordon fields are different.
First in schrodinger field $\Psi$  is wrttien in one variable($a$), while klein gordon field is written in two variables. ($a, a^{\dagger}$).
Second the factor of $2w_k$ comes out. I guess this comes from the Lorentz invariance of measure $\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3 2w_k}$.
hmm, in this sense, i guess Lorentz invariance is key difference between two theories.

Can anyone gives some reliable explanation about the difference between Schrodinger fields and Klein-Gordon fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Klein-Gordon equation describes massive relativistic particles (scalar boson) which satisfy the equation: 
$$E_p^2 = p^2 + m^2$$
Thus the energy (or equivalently $\omega$) has 2 solutions for a given momentum $E_p = \pm \sqrt{p^2 + m^2}$. Therefore, a general solution is necessarily a linear superposition of the solution with $E>0$ and the other with $E<0$ justifying the 2 terms in the Fourier development. The normalization with $\frac{1}{2\omega_k}$ is the relativistic normalization valid even when you change the frame with a boost (as you suggested in your question).

For Schrodinger, the energy is non-relativistic satisfying $E = \frac{p^2}{2m}$ and thus admitting only 1 solution for a given momentum. The Fourier transform is then simpler.

Comment: @phy_math: Your expansion is in values $\pm p^\mu = \pm (E, \vec{p})$ and not in $\pm E$. Also, there are complex field solutions of the KGE, for which the usuall Schrödinger-Ansatz is correct

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the second equation is just a way of writing the field as a hermitian field-operator. This is usually not required for [Schrödinger-fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_field#Field_Hamiltonian), since the field-equations incorperate complex numbers, while the KGE does not. This allows the KG-fields to be "real-valued"/hermitian (though "complex-valued"/non-hermitian fields are in princpile fine, too).